# NLOPT adding multiple mconstraint does not work

Tags: c++, optimization, constraints, nlopt

My code looks like this.

```
nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LD_SLSQP, dimension);

opt.set_min_objective(objective, NULL);

opt.add_inequality_mconstraint(constraint1, NULL, tolerance1);
opt.add_equality_mconstraint(constraint2, NULL, tolerance2);
opt.add_equality_mconstraint(constraint3, NULL, tolerance3);

opt.set_xtol_rel(1e-6);
opt.set_ftol_rel(1e-6);
opt.set_lower_bounds(lb);
opt.set_upper_bounds(ub);
opt.set_maxeval(MAX_EVAL);

initial_guess(result_vector);
opt.optimize(result_vector, min_cost);
```

Optimizing with 1 constraint returns good result.

But when I use them together, optimizer does not work properly. (each constraint is not satisfied)

Any idea why this is happening???

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation ([NLopt Introduction](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Introduction#Equality_constraints)):

> In principle, each equality constraint can be expressed by two inequality constraints ..., so you might think that any code that can handle inequality constraints can automatically handle equality constraints. In practice, this is not true—if you try to express an equality constraint as a pair of nonlinear inequality constraints, some algorithms will fail to converge.

My best guess is that the combination of inequality constraints would prevent the optimizer from converging.  If your constraints do produce an equality constraint, the introduction suggests using this to solve one parameter in terms of one (or more) other parameters.

EDIT: I also notice that your ftol and xtol values are the same; the introduction also recommends against this, as from the Taylor series expansion near the optimum, the error in the objective scales as the square of the error in x.